A problem in the proof of mapping formual (H →P) in stein Complex Analysis chapter8
We know that $F$ is a conformal map of $\mathbb{H}$ to $P$ ($P$ is  a polygon)
Let$$
h_{k}(z)=(F(z)-a_{k})^{ \frac{1}{\alpha_{k}}}
$$
Then
$$
\frac{F^{''}(z)}{F^{'}(z)}=-\beta_{k} \frac{h^{'}_{k}(z)}{h_{k}(z)}+ \frac{h^{''}_{k}(z)}{h^{'}_{k}(z)}
$$
and $h^{'}_{k}(z)\neq 0$ for all $z$ in the strip $A_{k-1}<\mathrm{Re}(z)<A_{k+1}$
We want to prove that
$$E_{k}(z)= \frac{F^{''}(z)}{F^{'}(z)}+ \frac{\beta_{k}}{z-A_{k}}=\beta_{k}\left( - \frac{h^{'}_{k}(z)}{h_{k}(z)}+ \frac{1}{z-A_{k}} \right)+ \frac{h^{''}_{k}(z)}{h^{'}_{k}(z)}$$ is holomorphic.
Since $h^{'}_{k}(z)\neq 0$ , $\frac{h^{''}_{k}(z)}{h^{'}_{k}(z)}$ is holomorphic.So it suffices to show that
$$
\frac{h^{'}_{k}(z)}{h_{k}(z)}- \frac{1}{z-A_{k}}= \frac{F^{'}(z)}{\alpha_{k}[F(z)-F(A_{k})]}-\frac{1}{z-A_{k}}
$$
is holomorphic,we need to show that it's bounded near $A_{k}$ ,How to prove it?
The picture below includes more information.

